# How do you get the children of a Tk Widget?

Tags: widget, tcl, hierarchy, tk-toolkit

How do tell a Tk widget to tell me what (or who as the case may be) its children are? Is there a command for this?

For example given a canvas widget `.cvs` with a label, a button and other adornments ... How do interrogate the canvas?

Answer (score 9):

```
winfo children $widget
```

see http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M8